# How to convert ArrayList into JList object? java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that gets larger as more users join a chatroom. The main JFrame has a list box that displays all currently connected users. But when i try to pass the arraylist into the jframe list i get this following error:

> "The method setListData(Object[]) in the type JList is not applicable
>   for the arguments (ArrayList)"

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use `list.toArray()` or individually loop over the arraylist and add the elements to the JList

Comment: I think you should have pass like this *JList list = new JList(arl.toArray());*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `setListData(arrayList.toArray())`

Or you could write your own `ListModel`, which is backed by the `ArrayList`, for example...

```
public class ListBasedListModel<T> extends AbstractListModel<T> {

    private List<T> data;

    public ListBasedListModel(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T getElementAt(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
    }
}
```

Then you could just do `list.setModel(new ListBasedListModel(arrayList))` or some such

Have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

```
JList myJList = new JList(arrayList.toArray()); //arrayList should be your Array List
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JList delList = new JList(myArrayList.toArray());
```