# Populate a comboBox with one of the values of an Object from an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, combobox

I'm looking for a way to populate the JcomboBox with an ArrayList. I'd like the comboBox to display all of the professional career names that are inside each object element of the arrayList. Any tips on how to do this? or is it there a function that can instantly put on those strings into the comboBox?

This is the arrayList I've created:

```
ArrayList<Career> cList = new ArrayList<Career>();
```

This is what Career contains:

```
public class Career {

    private String careerName;
    private int careerTerm;
    private String careerCode;
}
```

Comment: You could do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847496/how-to-convert-arraylist-into-jlist-object-java/34847527#34847527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to add an ArrayList to a ComboBoxModel. You need to add each item in the ArrayList to the combo box in a loop.

You can add any Object to the model of the combo box.

Then you should then create a custom renderer to display a property of your custom Object.

See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for a general renderer to get you started.

You can also read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Providing Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for basic information about renderers.